# wpf datagrid row color changing not happening

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I am comparing row value from WPF Datagrid row item to database items, after finding a match I need to change the color of particular row in Datagrid.
Upto finding match is working fine

```
  foreach (System.Data.DataRowView rowview in dataGrid1.Items )
  {
    var Srow = dataGrid1.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(dataGrid1.SelectedItem) as DataGridRow;
    Srow.Background = Brushes.LightGreen;
  }
```

giving error (Null reference unhandled.) I tried all option keeping index, rowview.Row["Name"].....

Please any suggestion in welcome.

Comment: you should change the selectedItemTemplate instead of changing the background manually

Answer (score 0):

Hi I will suggest you to implement the ***LoadingRow*** Event, as changing your rows style will be more easy:

```
  //The event: 
   dataGrid1.LoadingRow += new EventHandler<DataGridRowEventArgs>(dataGrid1_LoadingRow);
```

Now the function that handle the event

```
  //Here come the function
   private void dataGrid1_LoadingRow(object sender, DataGridRowEventArgs e)
   {
     //your test here to see if they match...
       DataRowView row = (DataRowView)e.Row.Item;
       String Content = row.Row[i].ToString();
       if(Content = //Did it matche something ?)
       { 
         //If yes:
          e.Row.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 217, 77, 77));
         //or 
         e.Row.Background = Brushes.LightGreen;
       }
   }
```

That's it, let me know if it workes for you.

Comment: Hi i want to check the existing/listed items from Datagrid to Database items so LoadingRow event will help...?  Thanks.

Comment: Loading row is an Event which is triggerred each time a new row is on the way to being added to the Datagrid. This new Row in fact is on the initialising state, and not yet showing on the Datagrid. When this event is triggered, you can acess only the current row which is creating, you can then change the row's BackgroundColor, content etc. before the display stage. The event will be triggered, as many time as your Datagrid items count. You can easily define a global variable that save your position in the Datagrid to work with the Database rows.